# Why does implementing crossProduct with scala's iterators return an incorrect result?

Tags: scala, iterator

Here I'm defining `crossProduct` as a function that should return tuples for all possible pairs of items from the left list with items from the right list.

```
object CrossProduct {
  def crossProduct[A, B](left: TraversableOnce[A], right: TraversableOnce[B]): TraversableOnce[(A, B)] = {
    for {
      l <- left
      r <- right
    } yield (l, r)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val left = Vector("A", "B", "C")
    val right = Vector("1", "2", "3", "4")

    println("With Vector, Vector")
    crossProduct(left, right).foreach(println)

    println("With Iterator, Vector")
    crossProduct(left.toIterator, right).foreach(println)

    println("With Vector, Iterator")
    crossProduct(left, right.toIterator).foreach(println)

    println("With Iterator, Iterator")
    crossProduct(left.toIterator, right.toIterator).foreach(println)
  }
}
```

When I pass in a vector as the `right` argument, it returns the correct results.  When I pass in an iterator as the `right` argument, it fails to iterate to the second element of the `left` argument.  Why is this happening?

```
With Vector, Vector
(A,1)
(A,2)
(A,3)
(A,4)
(B,1)
(B,2)
(B,3)
(B,4)
(C,1)
(C,2)
(C,3)
(C,4)
With Iterator, Vector
(A,1)
(A,2)
(A,3)
(A,4)
(B,1)
(B,2)
(B,3)
(B,4)
(C,1)
(C,2)
(C,3)
(C,4)
With Vector, Iterator
(A,1)
(A,2)
(A,3)
(A,4)
With Iterator, Iterator
(A,1)
(A,2)
(A,3)
(A,4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because an `Iterator` is traversable once and *only once*.

When `left` goes to its next element, `right` has to start over from the beginning. An `Iterator` can't do that. After a single traversal it is empty.